# apt-get update not working in Ubuntu 20.04 WSL1

Tags: networking, apt, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I recently installed Ubuntu WSL1 in my company PC and ran this command to update my installation, It seems ping is successful but "apt-get" fails to connect and download. I need some help here to trouble shoot this

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
  Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (111: Connection refused)


W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (111: Connection refused) 

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to ping archive.ubuntu.com and it is showing me it's successful. but the apt-get update does not work ?

```
 ping archive.ubuntu.com
```

```
--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 220.761/221.066/221.704/0.251 ms
```

Comment: It seems that somehow the DNS only looks up IPv6, which might be the problem ..

Comment: I also tried running this command to force apt to use IPv4 addresses, but it still does not work!  ```apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Try a `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com` - Are you able to ping the v4 addresses?

Comment: I think I'm able to ping the v4 addresses,  Server:         10.88.80.151
Address:        10.88.80.151#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.39
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.36
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.39
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.38
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::15
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::19
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::16
Name:   archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had the same problem a while ago.

I wasn't able to ascertain why this was happening, but the solution I was recommended was this:

0. Make a backup of `/etc/apt/sources.list`
1. inside that file, replace the string `archive.ubuntu.com` with `si.archive.ubuntu.com` (I use "si" to download from slovenian archive - find a mirror closest to you)
2. Run `apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! changing to a https based mirror link worked for me, I chose https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/ BTW

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. I resolved it by following the below steps.

**Open terminal**

1. run `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
2. In the new line add

> nameserver 8.8.8.8

3. Save the file.
4. run `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my issues, I found out that the default apt archives links were "http" based which my network was blocking so I went to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to look for https supported mirror links. I chose https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/

I replaced http://archive.ubuntu.com and http://security.ubuntu.com with https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/ in /etc/apt/sources.list

Now I'm able to sudo apt-get update and upgrade.

Thanks to everyone for your support.